# Is there a way to print the final value of an increment, before incrementing it, in C++?

Tags: c++

##### EDIT TITLE (I changed the title because it was wrongly referring to macros and compilation time, leading to confusion about my question)

In order to help with the output of my tests in c++ programs, I print the test number before each test. Something like this output :

```
[1/2] test :
// some test

[2/2] test :
// some test
```

the numeration of the test is in two parts :

`[ <number of this test> / <total number of tests> ]`

If I add a test or remove one, I don't have to hard-written the `<number of this test>`, because it's an int that increment itself each time. But, I have to count the `<total number of test>` and write it down manually (for example, in a macro, but that could be a variable as well).

here is how the code looks like :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define N_TEST "2"

int     main() {
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << "\n[" << ++i << "/" N_TEST "] test something :\n";
    {
        // some tests here
    }

    std::cout << "\n[" << ++i << "/" N_TEST "] test another thing :\n";
    {
        // some different tests here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to fill the `<total number of tests>` automatically ?

Comment: What do you *actually* want?

Comment: Instead of runnings the tests immediately, register the tests (such as by doing a push_back into a vector), then the size of the container is the number of tests, then execute the tests in the container.

Comment: I think I have your question wrong. Do you mean to say that you just want a count of the number of times a single (the same) test case has been run or do you want the number of test that have been run (this may include multiple test cases)

Comment: @llualpu, unless it is absolutely necessary, I usually discourage the use of macros. Cases where you'd need a macro are very sparse and include some weird functionality (like printing the name of the function being executed and so on)

Comment: Not to mention `C++` and `C` are entirely different languages. The only thing common between them is the syntax!

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him I removed the comment because it didn't help at all. OP wants the total number of tests, and the `__COUNTER__` macro does not help much.

Comment: @llualpu, from the tags, I am guessing OP themselves does not know what they want!

Comment: @llualpu yes i know about the `__COUNTER__` macro, i don't think it does what i want :)

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him I don't understand what is not clear ? maybe it's because of my poor english. I'll try to edit / reformulate the question. I'll focus on c++, to avoid one ambiguity (i supposed the solution could be similar)

Comment: Again, what do you actually want? Do you simply want to count the number of times `N_TEST` has been called? if that is so, I frankly suggest stepping through a debugger, or using a struct instead which will have another counter that increments on every call.

Comment: what i really want is not having to manually write the total number of tests. I don't mind if it's via a macro or anything else

Comment: From your title, *Is there a way to make a macro count it's own occurences in C/C++?* Do you mean *Is there a way to make a macro count it's own calls in C/C++?*

Comment: *what i really want is not having to manually write the total number of tests. I don't mind if it's via a macro or anything else* `Needs more focus` it is!

Comment: Is an static or global variable do the job ?
something like this solution : https://pastebin.com/JtCQJhQa (write but not tested). edit : I made a mistake in exemple, it's not "bool ret ..." but "int ret"

Comment: @AntoineLaps ho, ok, I see know the confusion, my tests are all different !

Comment: _`Needs more focus` it is!_ since I don't know how to do what I want, and even if it's possible, I don't think I can focus more, or it will become a [XY Problem] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). My question seems clear to me about what I want to achieve. It's not clear however about how I want to achieve it

Comment: I think @Eljay is on the right track here with their comment: "Instead of runnings the tests immediately, register the tests (such as by doing a push_back into a vector), then the size of the container is the number of tests, then execute the tests in the container." To keep test registration boilerplate to a minimum, a sensible macro can be made :) See e.g. how GoogleTest does it.

Comment: @Thomas ok :) I'll try that

Comment: Eljay is the better method, but you can also use mine. But It's really bad compared to eljay method. An updated version with a macro and global variable: https://pastebin.com/3LamUtTD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you are asking for a macro. If possible better avoid macros. As suggested in a comment, you can register tests in a container and once you know how many tests there are in total, you can print the total together with the running test number:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> tests;
    tests.push_back(
        [](){
            std::cout << "hello test\n";
        }
    );
    tests.push_back(
        [](){
            std::cout << "hello another test.\n";
        }
    );

    int counter = 0;
    for (const auto& test : tests){
        std::cout << ++counter << "/" << tests.size() << " ";
        test(); 
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/hYxcqzcMP):

```
1/2 hello test
2/2 hello another test.
```

Comment: it's great. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use anything newer than `c++98` (school exercises), but I didn't mention it in the question, so I will mark your answer as true. And I will try to adapt it for `c++98`

Comment: @hugogogo, *what i really want is not having to manually write the total number of tests. I don't mind if it's via a macro or anything else* is what you commented on the post. Isn't that essentially what is happening here?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him thats what they said. lambdas are c++11 though

Comment: @hugogogo in principle the same can be done in c++98, it just requires more code to be written. You could use a vector of pointers to some test base class, with a `void run()` method, register them, and then call them all in a loop

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, no, as in OP was intending to avoid using a special variable to count the test cases. Also, lambdas may not be explicitly available in that form before C++11, but let's not forget, C++11 lambdas are pseudo-lambdas and are essentially `structs`

Answer (score 0):

I post here a solution using only c++98

I'm not sure anyone will see it, since my question was really badly asked

And I'm not sure it's useful, outside a school context, to avoid using c++11

And finally, I'm not sure my solution is very good or solid, but it works ;)

anyway :

`tests.h`

```
#ifndef TESTS_H
#define TESTS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

# define TEST(s) \
    {\
        test_title = #s;\
        struct tester : public test_base {\
            void func()

# define TESTEND \
        };\
        test = new(tester);\
        test->title = test_title;\
        test_list.push_back(test);\
    }

struct test_base {
        std::string title;
        virtual void func() {}
};

std::vector<test_base *> test_list;
test_base *test;
std::string test_title;

#endif
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    TEST(name of first test)
    {
        std::cout << "hello test.\n";
    }
    TESTEND

    TEST(name of second test)
    {
        std::cout << "hello another test.\n";
    }
    TESTEND

    int size = test_list.size();
    for (int i = 0, i < size, i++)
    {
        std::cout
            << "\n[" << i + 1 << "/" << size << "] "
            << test_list[i]->title << " :\n";
        test_list[i]->func();
    }
}
```

or, if I get rid of the macros, for clarity here :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct test_base {
        std::string title;
        virtual void func() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<test_base *> test_list;
    test_base *test;

    {
        struct tester : public test_base {
            void func()
            {
                std::cout << "hello test.\n";
            }
        };
        test = new(tester);
        test->title = "name of first test";
        test_list.push_back(test);
    }

    {
        struct tester : public test_base {
            void func()
            {
                std::cout << "hello another test.\n";
            }
        };
        test = new(tester);
        test->title = "name of first test";
        test_list.push_back(test);
    }

    int size = test_list.size();
    for (int i = 0, i < size, i++)
    {
        std::cout
            << "\n[" << i + 1 << "/" << size << "] "
            << test_list[i]->title << " :\n";
        test_list[i]->func();
    }
}
```

I use a local scope for each test, so I can define the struct `tester` again